# jQuery endswith for multiple values

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check endsWith for values inside an array? something like the one below

```
jQuery('.imageUrlText').val().endsWith(["jpg","jpeg"])
```

Currently I am using the below code,

```
jQuery('.imageUrlText:contains("jpg"):contains("jpeg")').length>0
```

Comment: _inside an array?_ or you are talking about HTMLCollection? and what is this object `jQuery('.imageUrlText')` can you add it in your question too?

Comment: endsWith only support one value per call. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: You will need to write logic to suit your need

Answer (score 0):

Try RegEx

```
jQuery('.imageUrlText').val().match(/(jpg|jpeg)$/)
```

Note: jpg|jpeg will match either of jpg or jpeg and $ says, it must be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `.filter(fn)`:

```
var imageUrlText = jQuery('.imageUrlText').filter(function(){
  return $(this).val().indexOf('jpg') != -1 || $(this).val().indexOf('jpeg') != -1
});

console.log(imageUrlText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will work.

`jQuery('.imageUrlText').val().match("(jpg|jpeg)$")`